# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException from resource audio file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

This error popped up in me developer console the other day and I do not understand the problem.

I am trying to play a `mp3` file located in my raw folder of my project.

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(pref.getString(Preferences.CONN_TONE,""));
                if(uri != null){
                    player.setDataSource(this, uri);
                }else{
                    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.default_tone); //error here
                }

                player.prepare();
            }
```

on this line `player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.default_tone);` it gives me an error saying `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` why is it throwing a string exception when I am giving it an int resource to play an mp3 file? Also why is this throwing the error on this user.

stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ecm2.android/ecm2.android.Dialogs.MessageBox}: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=7
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5454)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; regionStart=0; regionLength=7
at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength(String.java:593)
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1474)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.isStreaming(MediaPlayer.java:3847)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.isNeedAddProxyInfo(MediaPlayer.java:3856)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1103)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1031)
at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1002)
at ecm2.android.Dialogs.MessageBox.playTone(MessageBox.java:75)
at ecm2.android.Dialogs.MessageBox.onCreate(MessageBox.java:43)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5066)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1101)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2307)
```

Comment: What's the name of the file? Feels like that might be the cause.

Comment: the name of the file is `default_tone.mp3`

Comment: Hmmm, how about the URI?  If you debug and look at that value before you pass it to the create method (print it out in a log statement) what does that look like?  Still feel like the filename has something to do with it, although default_tone.mp3 does seem like a pretty safe filename...

Comment: @Flynn81 the problem is I cannot debug this because this error does not happen to me, it happened to a user that downloaded the app and they reported the error to the developer console

Comment: Ok, how about the Uri default value, "".  Is it possible that your preference, Preferences.CONN_TONE, hasn't been set yet, and that prefs is returning ""?

Comment: @Flynn81 yes that is possible but wouldnt the parse return null? also it does not point to that line having the error though

Comment: No, I don't think it would.  The documentation states that parse will only throw a nullpointerexception if the string passed in is null.  Try installing the app clean in an emulator or device, make sure you avoid whatever action could set the preference, and then try and trigger the crash.

Comment: Also, if you have a bogus Uri, that would cause the crash in the media player, if it is trying to get a substring of your Uri.

Comment: @Flynn81 ok thanks make the last 2 lines the answer and I will accept it

Comment: change to pref.getString(Preferences.CONN_TONE, null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the `Preferences.CONN_TONE` has been set, or that the default value points to a default mp3 file that your app has.  Best guess is that an invalid Uri is being created by passing "" in to `Uri.parse()`, which is causing the exception down the line when `MediaPlayer.create()` is called using what is probably an invalid Uri.